# How to write a python function called automatically?

Tags: python-2.7, openerp-7

how to write a Python function who is called automatically in openerp without an event or a button, i have writed the function but now i called it with a button, but it must be called automatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

function field will get automatically call without any event or button.

If store=True will store the value of the field in database.

Once stored then the functional fields function will not be executed again. 
If 'store'=False, then every time(any change in the record) the functional field will be executed

from this link you can get more detail: [[https://doc.openerp.com/trunk/server/03_module_dev_02/#functional-fields][1]](https://doc.openerp.com/trunk/server/03_module_dev_02/#functional-fields%5d%5b1%5d)

Hope this help.